# AWS DynamoDb Update Failed After Retry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

From AWS Lambda I am updating AWS DynamoDb Table with "ConditionExpression" as updatedTimeStamp should match with the table data. Even if it fails it will try to get updated document data from the same table with ConsistentRead as true and try to update with the latest updatedTimeStamp. But still it's throwing "ConditionalCheckFailedException". Thanks in advance if any solution to this.

Code To Get Item:

```
    async function getItem(Id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let params = {
            ConsistentRead: true,
            TableName: process.env.TABLE,
            Key: {
                Id: Id,
            },
        };
        documentClient.get(params, async function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Code To Update:

```
async updateDataIntoDB(data, formdata, updatedTimestamp, index) {
        try {
            const params = {
                TableName: process.env.TABLE,
                ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
                Key: {
                    Id: Id,
                },
                UpdateExpression: `set #updatedTimestamp = :currentTimestamp, #brandProfile.#additionalAttributes.#forms.#index = :formdata, #updatedForm = :updatedForm, #updatedFormStatus = :updatedFormStatus, #updatedBy = :updatedBy, #callStepFunction = :callStepFunctionVal`,
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#brandProfile": "brandProfile",
                    "#additionalAttributes": "additionalAttributes",
                    "#forms": "forms",
                    "#index": index,
                    "#updatedForm": "updatedForm",
                    "#updatedFormStatus": "updatedFormStatus",
                    "#updatedBy": "updatedBy",
                    "#callStepFunction": "callStepFunction",
                    "#updatedTimestamp": "updatedTimestamp",
                },
                ConditionExpression: "updatedTimestamp = :updatedTimestamp",
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":formdata": <formdata>,
                    ":updatedFormStatus": <updatedFormStatus>,
                    ":updatedForm": <updatedForm>,
                    ":callStepFunctionVal": <callStepFunction>,
                    ":updatedBy": <UpdatedBy>,
                    ":updatedTimestamp": updatedTimestamp, // for the conditional check
                    ":currentTimestamp": new Date().toISOString(),
                },
            };
            return await documentClient.update(params).promise();
        }
        catch (error) {
           Log.warn(`Failed In Updating DB- ${error}`);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The GetItem isn't the code which is causing your exception, it's your UpdateItem. Can you share the code you use to update the item, and also the item which you are updating, copied from the DynamoDB console, just remove any sensitive data.

Comment: No need to explicitly create promises with AWS SDK functions. Simply `return documentClient.get(...).promise()`.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the right `updatedTimestamp`? The issue might be on the logic on how that is being passed to `updateDataIntoDB`